# How to connect JACK Audio from windows to linux?

Tags: linux, windows, jack-audio

I'm trying to route a windows playback device to play all sound on a linux speaker set, but the first issue of course is connecting jack from windows to linux over my network.

Apparently the options are [netjack1, netjack2 and jack.trip](http://jackaudio.org/faq/netjack.html) which are all meant for the purpose of connecting jack over network, but I can't for the life of me figure out how it is supposed to be done. It seems that jack ships with netjack2 and netjack1 (net/netone) when installed on both windows and linux, i have managed to set both up and start them, however they are both in "client" mode. I need the windows one to be set up as a server for the linux client to connect to.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I currently have this weird ass setup where I hooked the windows output to a windows input and then forwarded that as a line-in/microphone through teamspeak 3 to a teamspeak 3 server on my linux host which then listens to it with anywhere from 0-300ms latency. It works but it's not so nice. I'd really appreciate an alternative solution. I would hook the output directly to my linux soundcard's line-in, but my X-Fi isn't behaving, could use my ICH though)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get audio playback working from Windows to Linux with netjack2.
I did a small write-up of it here: https://gist.github.com/kotarou3/3813bbf7833a0e4618f7fbe8a377872d

Partially quoting here for posterity:

> ## Stream audio from Windows to Linux
>
> Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 Redstone 1
>
> Both boxes need to be on the same network (such that multicast packets
>   can be passed between them)
>
> ### Installing
>
> #### Linux
>
> 1. Setup JACK (easy to do with [Cadence](http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/Applications:Cadence))
>
> #### Windows
>
> 1. Install JACK and [ASIO Bridge](http://vb-audio.pagesperso-orange.fr/Cable/) on the Windows
>      box
> 2. Run `regsvr32 32bits\JackRouter.dll` and `regsvr32 64bits\JackRouter.dll` from JACK installation directory
> 3. Modify `32bits\JackRouter.ini` and `64bits\JackRouter.ini` to match your channel and sample config
> 4. (Optional) Set the ASIO Bridge (*Hi-Fi Audio*) input as the default playback device
>
> ### Running
>
> 1. Start the netjack2 server on Linux with `jack_load netmanager` (probably also possible to add to `.jackdrc` for it to autoload)
> 2. Run JACK NetDriver on Windows (it's in the Start menu), or `jackd -R -d net`
> 3. A new device named the hostname of the Windows box should have appeared on the Linux JACK patch panel
>      ([Catia](http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/Applications:Catia) if you're
>      using Cadence). Connect it as you see fit (Note: Channels might not
>      match up as expected if you have more than 2).
> 4. Run ASIO Bridge (also in the Start menu), turn ASIO on, and set the ASIO device to JackRouter
> 5. The ASIO Bridge should have automatically set up routes to the system device in the Windows JACK patch panel. You can double check
>      with qjackctl (*Jack Control* in the Start menu) → *Connections*
>      and connect them if not

Comment: Ack, wish you'd come along sooner, my setup is quite different now with my speakers connected to the windows machine instead... but now I'm just having the reverse problem.
Still, I'll accept your answer since it looks legit and it's the only one I've got for a full year :P

Comment: [This blog post](https://blogs.gentoo.org/mgorny/2015/01/16/surround-sound-over-network-with-windows-8/) explains how to do Linux -> Windows. Once again, it involves JACK and netjack2, and the linux setup is trivial. On Windows, you install ASIO4ALL such that non-ASIO aware sound cards can be used as ASIO sinks, which JACK can use.